# Sci-fi show where humans defeat giants, then learn that they're children

Tags: story-identification, tv

My dad recalls an episode of a sci-fi show that either takes place on Earth or involves humans going to a different planet.  Anyways, in the episode, humans encounter giants and engage in battle.  The humans are finally victorious only to realize that those giants were just the children and now the adults are coming.   My dad doesn't recall which show this was.  I've looked at *The Twilight Zone* and *The Outer Limits*.  They don't have an episode like this.  Anyone know what it is?

Comment: Does your dad remember roughly when he saw it?

Comment: What decade? Was it in color or black & white? Does he remember any more details?

Comment: There were more shows like that; _[Monsters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Monsters_episodes)_ springs to mind. S1E15 is about monstrous worms guarding a melon patch; and in the end after the protagonists have fought and defeated them, the  worms' mother turns up.

Comment: He says it's black and white.   He also said the worms show was not it.

Comment: Now he says he's unsure if it was black and white.

Comment: @user89402 Can you add that into the question? It is valuable information which shouldn't be in a comment.

Answer (score 6):

While you say it isn't The Outer Limits, it certainly sounds like an episode I remember from the 90s version of the show.  The episode was called ["Relativity Theory"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_Theory_(The_Outer_Limits))(Season 4, episode 6).

The aliens the humans kill turn out to be the equivalent of alien boy scouts on a camping trip, which is why they only have primitive technology.  The world they are on is alien to both species.  At the end, the parents turn up in a much more advanced space ship with an intent to punish the human race for killing their children.  They aren't giants, but the gist of the story seems to be the same.

A [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQuOGJeLj9o) from the episode.